# Simple conditions on Radon-Nikodym derivative to obtain equivalent measures

Tags: measure-theory

Are there some simple conditions for the converse statement of the following statement:

> If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent (i.e. $\mu \ll \nu$ and $\nu \ll \mu$) then
> $$
> \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=\left(\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)^{-1}
> $$

Is strict positivity of the derivate one for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\frac{\mu}{\nu}$ is not strictly positive almost everywhere, then that means there is a $\nu$-non-null set where $\frac{\mu}{\nu}$ vanishes, thus $\mu$ vanishes on that set, hence, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not equivalent. Conversely, if $\frac{\mu}{\nu}$ is strictly positive almost everywhere, then on every $\nu$-non-null set, the integral of $\frac{\mu}{\nu}$ should be nonzero, thus $\mu$ and $\nu$ should be equivalent.